# How to reset Id of list_view item in each tab in TabHost?

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I have a layout in which there is two tab(implemented by "TabHost"), and in each tab I have a list_view with one item.
as I found, the Id of the first item in the list_view which is in the second tab, starts from 1 instead of zero. I know this id is the continuation of the id of the last item of the first tab (As shown in the following images)

Now the question is *How to make these id to start from zero for each tab?* .

first consider this part for filling list view in All Tabs.

```
// Tab1
TabHost.TabSpec LawSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Law_SPEC);
LawSpec.setIndicator(Law_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.searchimg));
Intent LawIntent = new Intent(ListResult.this, LawResult.class);
LawIntent.putExtra("Lawlist", LawList);
LawSpec.setContent(LawIntent);

//  Tab2
TabHost.TabSpec ArticleSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Article_SPEC);
ArticleSpec.setIndicator(Article_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.searchimg));
Intent ArticleIntent = new Intent(ListResult.this, ArticleResult.class);
ArticleIntent.putExtra("Articlelist", ArticleList);
ArticleSpec.setContent(ArticleIntent);
```

And in each Tab I have a ListAdapter:

```
// Tab1's List
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    LawResult.this, LawList, R.layout.law_result_item,
    new String[]{"selectedId", TAG_body, TAG_tag},
    new int[]{R.id.idL, R.id.body, R.id.tags}
);
setListAdapter(adapter);


// Tab2's List Adapter
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    ArticleResult.this, ArticleList, R.layout.article_result_item,
    new String[]{"selectedId", TAG_body, TAG_tag},
    new int[]{R.id.idA, R.id.body, R.id.tags}
);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: tab1]

[image: tab2]

Comment: Show how are you setting up that listview and also the adapter class.

Comment: Have you tried using getListView().setSelection(0) in your second activity

Comment: question missing vital details. what is the id you're talking about? where and how do you define ArticleList?  (ps. variable name should start with lower case - a convention)